# Run React dev server as background process?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, centos

I've been recently experimenting with React and I want to be able to run the dev server that's initialized when you run npm start in the react app's directory as a background process on centOS so that I can continue to use the command line.

Is this possible with something like pm2? I tried various commands but couldn't get it to work, of course I can do the following "nohup npm start &" but I would much rather have all my managed processes using pm2 or some other process manager maybe?

Any advice?

Comment: react-devserver is a dev server why would you want pm2 in the mix?